# Codeigniter 3 application bug: logged in user's avatar does not update in real time

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I am working on a basic **[blog application](https://github.com/Ajax30/lightblog)** with Codeigniter 3.1.8 and Bootstrap 4.

The application has user (author) accounts. There is a problem with displaying the photo (avatar) of the logged-in before the session is destroyed, due to the fact that I display the avatar from the session (header.php view):

```
<?php if ($this->session->userdata('user_avatar')): ?>
    <img src="<?php echo base_url('assets/img/authors/') . $this->session->userdata('user_avatar'); ?>" class="avatar" />
<?php else: ?>  
    <img src="<?php echo base_url('assets/img/authors/') . 'default-avatar.png' ?>" class="avatar" />
<?php endif ?>
```

That seemed like a good idea at the time, an easy and logical implementation of the avatar display, until the update problem revealed. Of course, I have to logout and login again to see my avatar in the website's header, as I had to admit. :(

In the model I have:

```
public function update_user($avatar, $id) {
        $data = [
            'first_name' => $this->input->post('first_name'),
            'last_name' => $this->input->post('last_name'),
            'email' => $this->input->post('email'),
            'bio' => $this->input->post('bio'),
            'avatar' => $avatar
        ];

        $this->db->where('id', $id);
        return $this->db->update('authors', $data);
    }
```

In the Login controller I have:

```
public function login() {  
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'required|trim|valid_email');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required|trim');
    $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<p class="error-message">', '</p>');
    if ($this->form_validation->run()) {
        $email = $this->input->post('email');
        $password = $this->input->post('password');
        $this->load->model('Usermodel');
        $current_user = $this->Usermodel->user_login($email, $password);
        // If we find a user
        if ($current_user) {
            // If the user found is active
            if ($current_user->active == 1) {
                $this->session->set_userdata(
                    array(
                        'user_id' => $current_user->id,
                        'user_email' => $current_user->email,
                        'user_avatar' => $current_user->avatar,
                        'user_first_name' => $current_user->first_name,
                        'user_is_admin' => $current_user->is_admin,
                        'user_active' => $current_user->active,
                        'is_logged_in' => TRUE
                    )
                );
                // After login, display flash message
                $this->session->set_flashdata('user_signin', 'You have signed in');
                //and redirect to the posts page
                redirect('/');  
            } else {
                // If the user found is NOT active
                $this->session->set_flashdata("login_failure_activation", "Your account has not been activated yet.");
                redirect('login'); 
            }
        } else {
            // If we do NOT find a user
            $this->session->set_flashdata("login_failure_incorrect", "Incorrect email or password.");
            redirect('login'); 
        }
    }
    else {
        $this->index();
    }
}
```

What would be an easy to implement bugfix?

Comment: Your question is not very clear, but if I understand correctly, if a user updates their avatar, the avatar displayed in the header does not change?  If the displayed image comes from the session, then `update_user()` should [update the value in the session](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/sessions.html#adding-session-data), right?

Comment: @Don'tPanic Right. Or maybe there is some alternative, like displaying the avatar, _not_ from the session, but in a different way.

Comment: There are a thousand ways to do it.  You've chosen one which is perfectly fine, efficient, very standard.  But you've left it half-done ...

Comment: @Don'tPanic Actually, I may need a solution that does not pull the photo from the session because any session is per user.

Comment: @Don'tPanic Perhaps a solution that involves the user's id - because it does _not change_ - and the _coresponding_ avatar would be best?

Comment: Your question is getting more unclear with every comment!  Yes, a session is per-user, that's also how logins work.  But who else except the logged-in user should be viewing the logged-in user's avatar in the header?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [codeigniter session](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html) documentation, you can use something like this:

`$this->session->set_userdata('user_avatar', $new_user_avatar);`

Of course you need to add this in your code somewhere above the place you display the avatar.

For `$new_user_avatar` you'll even need to re-query the database after the avatar update, or you simple update the session after getting the form after you upload the file.

Acordingly to your code:

1. In login controller you are setting up in array the session.
2. with update_user in model you are updating your avatar.
3. You are displaying in header view from session.

Your question is how to update the avatar. 
In the moment you use the update_user model, you have 2 options:
1. you also update the session with the specific avatar. 
2. your run this function

`$current_user = $this->Usermodel->user_login($email, $password);
array['user_avatar'] = $current_user->first_name`

So final solution would be:

`$this->session->set_userdata('user_avatar', $avatar);` should go after `$avatar = $_FILES['userfile']['name'];` in the controller (line 91).

Comment: I have this line in the model: `'avatar' => $avatar` and the value of `$avatar` comes from the controller. But when `$avatar` changes in the controller, it does not update in the model _until_ the current session is destroyed and a new one created. :(

Comment: In controllers/dashboard/Users.php after
`$avatar = $this->input->post('avatar');` on line 84
add 
`$this->session->set_userdata('user_avatar', $avatar);`

Comment: In fact, `$this->session->set_userdata('user_avatar', $avatar);` should go after `$avatar = $_FILES['userfile']['name'];` in the controller (line 91). Add this to your answer so that anyone can benefit from it and so that I can validate the answer. Thanks!

Comment: Hi @RazvanZamfir updated the post. Glad that I could help you.